# which one is correct? said to not go VS said not to go

Tags: grammar

I learned "not to go" is right but sometimes I could find "to not go"
what's correct?

ex) She said not to go there.
ex) She said to not go there.

Answer (score 0):

*She said to not go there* is a mixture of direct and indirect speech. For example maybe in direct speech, she said "Do not go there."

You could punctuate differently to see this:

> John: What did your mother say about going to the club?
>
> Mary: She said to "not go there".

Comment: Is your example meant to show normal usage or abnormal usage?

Comment: I hear this form frequently in the area where I live (South of England). I can't speak for other geographical locations. I see it as casual rather then formal speech.

Comment: OK. For the record to an American it sounds very very wrong without "do" attached on the front.